# RFI makes 10m almost unusable

Tags: hf, rfi

Seeing a lot of solid vertical lines on the spectrum scope of my ftdx10 and they’re really annoying.

I have a yaesu fp1023a powering and ftdx10. Doesn’t go away if I turn off every circuit in the house except the one powering my radio. Antenna is outside also. Gonna order a battery to see if it’s the power supply.

Anyone know what’s going on (new ham here)

[image]

Comment: It's hard for me to tell, but it looks like the red lines are about 20 kHz apart. Switching power supplies and solar inverters are usually 25 kHz. Not too far off. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: Does this occur 24 hours a day?

Comment: @MikeWaters you’re good! 20khz is the spacing on 10m. I believe the same RFI is present on 80m but at 30khz spacing. It’s 24 hours a day.

Comment: I may be wrong but I don’t recall seeing it on 40 or 20m

Comment: Do you have a 40 or 20m antenna? If you're only using a 10m antenna, then that might explain why you don't see it on those lower bands.

Comment: The 30 kHz spaced RFI on 80 is likely not the same source.

Comment: I have a 40/20/10 efhw in a tree outside in an inverted vee. It’s a vibroplex Ef-quad

Answer (score 4):

Your S-meter is showing 0, so unless you have an attenuator in I don't think there's an actual noise problem here. There's just no signals in the band so the noise (which isn't all that strong) is all you see. If there *were* any signals they would probably stand out against the noise just fine.

Comment: Good catch. I was focused on the waterfall.

Comment: Can’t tell if I have the att on or if it’s ipo or amp1 because I maximized the waterfall (oops) but  I have to notch out these signals when someone is transmitting near them if the tx station signal isn’t really big and strong. The notch filter distorts the audio pretty heavily sometimes depending on where the station is in relation to the RFI.

Answer (score 1):

Chris,  WSPR is gonna be your friend.  You can find if the band is opening by looking at WSPR maps, when you see contacts in your area, then you will know there will be some signals up.  If things are happening, usually FT8 signals will be at 28.074 and maybe some SSB between 28.350-28.400.  You can also wander down to the CB frequencies to look for US path openings.  Sometimes the 11 meter band opens just before the 10 meter band.

Comment: Thanks, waiting on my wspr account to be activated. I check for 10m opening currently by pulling up a Websdr site about 100mi from my qth and looking for ft8 or ssb

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a train of pulses with a repetition frequency of about 20 kHz. The pulses are not quite wideband because they are absent above about 28.63 MHz. If you tune towards lower frequencies you can presumably find a low end for where these pulses occur. The wider the spectrum is, the better is the chance to remove these pulses with a high bandwidth noise blanker. If you have access to an oscilloscope going up to or above 30 MHz you might be able to see these pulses in the time domain. Maybe you would need a high pass filter to not saturate the oscilloscope wit strong signals from the lower bands.

You might be interested in these links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5asxOcRDdXo

http://sm5bsz.com/blanker.htm

http://sm5bsz.com/linuxdsp/blanker/wide.htm

http://sm5bsz.com/linuxdsp/rxiq/demo/blanker.htm

http://sm5bsz.com/linuxdsp/blanker/leonids.htm

http://sm5bsz.com/linuxdsp/blanker/leon2001/leon2001.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMd5y036HtA